# Handling Errors and Success Responses with Inertia.js and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm currently working on a project that utilizes Inertia.js and Laravel, and I'm encountering difficulties with handling errors and success responses. I've followed the documentation and tried various approaches, but I'm unable to achieve the desired behavior.

One specific issue I'm facing is related to the onError and onSuccess callbacks in my Inertia.js request. For some reason, only the onBefore callback is functioning as expected. Whenever an error occurs, instead of being able to handle it within my Vue.js component, Laravel returns a "500 Internal Server Error" page. I have already configured Laravel to return JSON responses for API requests.

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using in my Vue.js component:

Front-end code:

```
   router.post(route("posts.update", this.tweet.id), formData, {
    onBefore: () => confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?"),
    onError: () => {
        return Promise.all([confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?")]);
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
        return Promise.all([confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?")]);
    },
});
```